# rails 3 test case error.on(:field) Vs. errors[:field]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on the Rails 3 Test cases . While writing case i got Deprecation error like

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Errors#on have been deprecated, use Errors#[] instead.
Also note that the behaviour of Errors#[] has changed. Errors#[] now always returns an Array. An empty Array is returned when there are no errors on the specified attribute. (called from on at /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_model/deprecated_error_methods.rb:7)
```

For that i used errors[:field] instead of errors.on(:field)
Now Deprecation error is gone , but cases are not working as earlier it was working . It is not testing any validation for the model

Sol

Comment: the question is errors.on(:field) in rails unit test in showing deprecation error and errors[:field] not working properly .. is there any way to solve this issue .

Answer (score 9):

Replace:

```
errors.on(:field)
```

with:

```
errors.include?(:field)
```

Answer (score 7):

After searching for examples of how to do this without finding anything I ended up doing:

```
errors[:field].present? /  errors[:field].blank?
```

Don't know if this is the preferred way but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 4):

I am using something like this at the moment:

```
@hamburger.errors[:ingredients].count.should == 1
@hamburger.errors[:ingredients].should include "Tomatoes are missing dude!"
```

Hope it helps someone, right now it is the cleanest solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm converting my old specs to something like this to remove the deprecation warnings:

```
  model.should have(1).error_on(:field)
  model.should have(:no).errors_on(:field)
```